# Your application is staging to create bluemix node-red app

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am a newbie for the bluemix. I would like to start the Node red app. However the app will never be created, instead the screen always show Your application is staging. I have try this a number of times and changed the server location from UK to USA. However it never works.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: And how long did you wait to see if it finishes staging?

Comment: I have waited for 2 ~4 hours . also I tried to change the server region and changed the Space for apps.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Have you exceeded your quota?

Comment: I do not get any error message instead the application just can not be build .

Answer (score 2):

it is a known issue about a node.js module not building correctly. There is already a fix about the module, we are waiting for the npm repository to be updated. https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/pull/44/commits

Comment: You mean what I can do is just to wait until the bug will be fixed.

Comment: @Hiroshi : The fix has been published and I have just successfully deployed an instance of the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the node-red code from the official [GitHub](https://github.com/node-red/node-red) then push it to Bluemix. Another thing that you could do is use the node-red inside a [Docker](https://nodered.org/docs/platforms/docker) and also push it to Bluemix.

Comment: This question was about a very specific error back in 2015 that was fixed within hours of it being reported. I'm not sure this answer adds anything to this very specific and old question